Dual space of local Sobolev space on a manifold
$\newcommand{\comp}{\mathrm{comp}}$As part of my master's thesis, I am currently learning about Sobolev spaces on manifolds.  From my research online, I found out, that there are a lot of ways to define Sobolev spaces on manifolds, which are not equivalent to each other. I have decided to use local Sobolev spaces, because they are the easiest to define and do not need further assumptions on the manifold.  I have found one treatment in [1], where the local Sobolev spaces are used, which I have been going through, but [1] is very minimalistic in its presentation and therefore some things are not clear.
The setting is the following:
Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, $(x_i, U_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ a countable atlas, such that $U_i\subseteq M$ is a relatively compact open set and $(\phi_j)_{j\in\mathbb N}$ a partition of unity subordinate to the atlas. Then we define the local Sobolev space on M as
$$H^s_{loc}(M):=\{u\in\mathcal D'(M)| x_j^{-1}(\phi_ju)\in H^s(\mathbb R^n)\}, $$
where $\mathcal D'(M)$ is the dual space of the test functions (here we need the metric g to include smooth functions as distributions), $H^s(\mathbb R^n)$ is the Sobolev Space on $\mathbb R^n$  and $x_j^{-1}(\phi_ju)\in \mathcal E'(\mathbb R^n)$ (=dual space of smooth functions) is defined as
$$x_j^{-1}(\phi_ju)[h]:=u[\phi_j(h\circ x_j)]\ \text{for}\ h\in\mathcal E(\mathbb R^n).$$
We denote the sobolev distributions with compact support as $H^s_{\comp}(M)$. We equip $H^s_{loc}(M)$ with the countable family of seminorms
$$\Vert u\Vert_{i, s}:=\Vert x_j^{-1}(\phi_ju)\Vert_{H^s(\mathbb R^n)}$$
to turn it into a Fréchet space. To equip $H^s_{\comp}(M)$ with a topology, we first equip
$$H^s(K):=\{u\in H^s_{loc}(M)| supp(u)\subset K\},$$
where $K\subset M$ is compact with the scalar product
$$\langle u, v \rangle_{H^s(K)}:=\sum_{j=0}^{j_0(K)}\langle x_j^{-1}(\phi_ju), x_j^{-1}(\phi_jv) \rangle_{H^s(\mathbb R^n)},$$
where $j_0(K)$ is the maximal index j with $K\cap U_j\ne \emptyset$. Then we equip $H^s_{\comp}(M)$ with the final topology induced by the maps
$$i_K:H^s(K)\to H^s_{\comp}(M)\ \text{for}\  K\subset M\  \text{compact}.$$
Now, my  question is

How do you prove, that $H^s_{loc}(M)^*=H^{-s}_{\comp}(M)$ and $H^{s}_{\comp}(M)^*=H^{-s}_{loc}(M)$ for $s\in\mathbb R^n$ ?

It is now stated in [1] that one can define a pairing
$$\langle u, v \rangle:= \langle \Lambda_s u,\Lambda_s v \rangle-\langle R_s u,v \rangle$$
for $u\in H^s_{loc}(M),v\in H^{-s}_{\comp}(M)$, where $\Lambda_s$ is an elliptic Pseudodifferential operator, such that $\Lambda_{-s}$ is a parametrix and $R_s$ is the residual smoothing operator, i.e. $\Lambda_s \Lambda_{-s}=id+R_s$. While it is clear to me how to define the first term , since  $\Lambda_s u\in L_{2,loc}(M),\Lambda_s v\in L_{2,\comp}(M)$ such that their product can be integrated, it is unclear to me for the second term .
Furthermore, it is stated in [1] that for every $l\in H^s_{loc}(M)^*$, there exists a $v\in H^{-s}_{\comp}(M)$ such that $l(u)=\langle u,v \rangle$, because $l\circ \Lambda_{-s}\in L_{2,loc}(M)^*$ and the assertion is clear for $s=0$.
Now, even if I assume that it is clear for $s=0$, one could only follow
$$l(u)=l(\Lambda_s \Lambda_{-s}u)-l(R_su)=\langle \Lambda_su,v \rangle-l(R_su)$$
for some $v\in L_{2,\comp}(M)$. I don't see, how the assertion follows for general $s\in\mathbb R$.
I would be grateful for either some explanation on the proof in [1] or another proof entierly. I  feel fairly confident with functional analysis, Sobolev spaces on $\mathbb R^n$ as well as basic manifold theory. Just the combination is still new to me.
[1] Shubin, M. A. (2001). Pseudodifferential Operators and Spectral Theory.
Springer Berlin, Heidelberg. doi: https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-56579-3.
